# If, Else, limit range in google script for onEdit trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, slack, google-workspace

When the value in the cells changes, a message is sent to Slack. I was able to configure sending messages for any change. Here is the script:

```
var url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/';

function sampleName(e){
    
  var newValue = e.value; 
  var oldValue = e.oldValue; 
  var user = e.user; 
  
  var payload = {
      'text' : user + " Изменено с " + oldValue + " на "  + newValue  + " :wink:"
    };

  var params = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'contentType' : 'application/json',
      'payload' : JSON.stringify(payload)
    };
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)

}
```

But I want it only to send a message if the change is in a certain place.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: For example: when a change occurs in cells B2 so that only then the notification is sent to Slack. Now the script works in such a way that any change is sent to Slack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Take a look at the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

For example:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
    
    let eventRange = e.range;
    let eventRow = eventRange.getRow()
    let eventCol = eventRange.getColumn()
    
    
    if (eventRow == 1 && eventCol == 1) {
        // DO STUFF
        // ...
        // etc
    }
}
```

- The event object, usually called `e`, has a range attribute.
- Get the column and the row from this and then use conditionals as you need.
- You can also call the `source` attribute to get the Sheet name and use that in your coditionals also.
- Inspect the documentation linked in the title to see all the different info you can get from the event object, its a lot!